# Core Data - Delete rule

Tags: core-data

I'm following Apple's documentation about [Relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-CJBDBHCB). In their example, a Department has a to-many relationship to the Employees that work in a Department, and there is an inverse relationship from an Employee to the Department.

What should be the delete rule from Employee to Department? When I delete an employee, I don't want to change anything in the department, so the rule would be "No Action", which gives me a warning. I suppose I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nullify, which means that if a department is deleted the relationship on the Employee site will be set to nil.

Comment: There are 2 relationships: Department to employee and employee to department, right? I understand that department to employee should have the delete rule as nullify. But I'm asking the other way around. If I delete an Employee and the delete rule between Employee and Department is nullify, what happens to the Department? Will the department be set to null?

Comment: I think you should also use Nullify, so it will remove the relationship from the set.

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025598/when-my-relationship-delete-rule-is-set-to-nullify-will-the-inverse-relationship

Comment: The department will not be set to null. The department's _employee_ will be nullified, or in the case of a to-many rule, the department's employees will have an entry removed. If delete rule for Department.employees is also nullify, then when you delete the department, its employees are _not_ let go. The employees _department_ is set to null.

Comment: If, when you close a department, you want to lay off the employees, choose **cascade**. Maybe it's better to choose **deny**, which would force you to write code to reassign or lay off employees before closing the department. **Nullify** could be ok if your Employees' department relationship is optional. That is, it's ok to use nullify if you don't mind having employees on your payroll that aren't doing any job.